# Get the last Windows Update install date using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, vbscript, windows-update

I am trying to write a PowerShell script that will query all the servers in Active Directory and see the last date a Windows Update was applied.

I was having some trouble, so just to get it done, I created two scripts, one in Powershell to get the servers and the other in VBScript to query the last date.  I found a this Powershell [module](http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/2d191bcd-3308-4edd-9de2-88dff796b0bc) that allows me to query the last install date, but it is *extremely* slow, especially on remote servers.

Here is the PS code:

```
Get-ADComputer -Filter 'OperatingSystem -like "*Server*"' -Properties * |
Select-Object Name | Sort-Object Name |
ForEach-Object {
    Get-WUHistory -ComputerName $_.Name | Sort-Object Date,ComputerName -Descending |
    Select-Object -First 1
}
```

Its so slow, its practically unusable.

I have some VBScript which I cobbled together that is *much* faster.  See below:

```
On Error Resume Next
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set file = fso.OpenTextFile ("servers.csv", 1)
server = ""

Do Until file.AtEndOfStream
  line = file.Readline
  server = line
  'wscript.echo server
  Set objSession = CreateObject("Microsoft.Update.Session", server)
  If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    'WScript.Echo server & " Error: " & Err.Number & " Error (Hex): " & Hex(Err.Number) & " Source: " &  Err.Source & " Description: " &  Err.Description
    WScript.Echo server & " Communications Error"
    Err.Clear
  Else
      Set objSearcher = objSession.CreateUpdateSearcher
      Set colHistory = objSearcher.QueryHistory(1, 1)
      For Each objEntry in colHistory
        Wscript.Echo server & " " & objEntry.Date
      Next
  End If
Loop

file.Close
```

Is there an easy way to get the speed of the VBScript into the Powershell code?

---

Here is the working Powershell code (modified again) if anyone is interested:

```
$ErrorActionPreference= 'silentlycontinue'
Get-ADComputer -Filter 'OperatingSystem -like "*Server*"' -Properties * | Select-Object Name |
ForEach-Object {
    If (Test-Connection $_.Name -Count 1){
        Get-HotFix -ComputerName $_.Name | Sort-Object InstalledOn -Descending | Select-Object -First 1 
    }
    else {
        Write-host $_.Name " Connection Error"
    }
} |
Sort-Object InstalledOn
```

Comment: I don´t see inhowfar the VBS code is comparable to the PowerShell code? The VBS iterates over a csv file´s lines, doing just one QueryHistory call for each line, while the Powershell version gets the history for each computer contained in a sorted list returned by a sorted property query containing LIKE, sorting it by date. That´s a nested subquery. Surely that takes more time. If you do the same in VBS, it would be as slow as the PowerShell version, I guess.

Comment: @TheBlastOne the slowness in the PowerShell script is from the PS module.  Running in the ISE, I can watch the progress bar for the module reading the servers update history and it takes forever.

Comment: I the working code looks like it works but it only outputs the hosts with connection errors.  Where are the other results going?  I don't see them output anywhere.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Powershell, How to get date of last Windows update install or at least checked for an update?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33732541/powershell-how-to-get-date-of-last-windows-update-install-or-at-least-checked-f)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Does `Get-HotFix` meet your needs?

```
Get-HotFix -ComputerName $_.Name | Measure-Object InstalledOn -Maximum
```

Your performance issues could be coming from `Get-ADComputer`. I'd do some troubleshooting to see which piece is causing you problems.

Comment: If you mean Get-ADComputer, then no thats pretty quick.  The slowness is definitely from Get-WUHistory.  Im trying get-hotfix now.

Comment: Yeah, that. Where'd I put that coffee?

Comment: This works at a reasonable speed.  Putting my amended script in the question.

Comment: Get-Hotfix does require Powershell 3.0 or greater, but a fair enough trade-off and as a bonus meets the requirement for many scenarios where a course-grained one-liner is enough.

Answer (score 9):

Tim Ferrill already provided you the answer but for the record you could have done something like this

```
$ScriptBlock = {
    $hash=@{}
    $Session = New-Object -ComObject Microsoft.Update.Session
    $Searcher = $Session.CreateUpdateSearcher()
    $hash[$env:Computername] = $Searcher.QueryHistory(1,1) | select -ExpandProperty Date
    $hash
}

Invoke-Command -ComputerName $serverlist -ScriptBlock $ScriptBlock
```

This would get you something like

```
Name                    Value
----                    -----
Server1                 5/16/2014 2:11:42 PM
Server2                 4/14/2014 1:55:03 PM
Server3                 5/6/2014 5:36:51 PM
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(get-hotfix -computername SERVERNAME | sort installedon)[-1] >> c:\file.txt
```

This will get you the last installed date.  I just use some excel work to clean up the output after you run it against all your server names.

Got that command from  "get-help get-hotfix -full"