# Powershell, How to get date of last Windows update install or at least checked for an update?

Tags: windows, powershell

I am trying to find a way of retrieving the date/time of which the last windows update was either installed, or checked for.

So far I have found a function that allows to list recent Windows Updates, but it is far too much data and too bloated for such a simple function. Secondly I have tried to access the registry although I am having no luck in retriving the value I am after.

I am testing this on a Windows 10 Machine although the software will probably reside on Windows Server 2012 R2.

Here is an example of some of the code I have tried:

```
$key = “SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WindowsUpdate\Auto Update\Results\Install” 
$keytype = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryHive]::LocalMachine 
$RemoteBase = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenBaseKey($keytype,"My Machine") 
$regKey = $RemoteBase.OpenSubKey($key) 
$KeyValue = $regkey.GetValue(”LastSuccessTime”) 

$System = (Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")
```

Also, just trying the Get-ChildItem

```
$hello = Get-ChildItem -Path “hkcu:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WindowsUpdate\”

foreach ($a in $hello) {

$a

}
```

I've checked in regedit and this key does not exist. Going to the "Windows Update" path shows only App Updates and not Windows updates.

EDIT
I seem to be closer to my goal with this line:
Get-HotFix | Where {$_.InstallDate -gt 30}

However how to I only retrive those of which have been installed in the last 30 days? And this doesnt show many results, even using `Select $_.InstallDate`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

an option :

```
 gwmi win32_quickfixengineering |sort installedon -desc
```

Another alternative, using the com object *Microsoft.Update.Session* can be find here : https://p0w3rsh3ll.wordpress.com/2012/10/25/getting-windows-updates-installation-history/
in short :

```
$Session = New-Object -ComObject Microsoft.Update.Session 
$Searcher = $Session.CreateUpdateSearcher()
$HistoryCount = $Searcher.GetTotalHistoryCount()
# http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa386532%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
$Searcher.QueryHistory(0,$HistoryCount) | ForEach-Object {$_}
```

Comment: Thats tidy, still not many results though, only 11. is this normal? Secondly, Is it possible to only get the last 30 days?

Comment: not tested, you could try `gwmi win32_quickfixengineering |sort installedon -desc |?{ ((get-date)-$_.installedon) -lt 30 }   `

Comment: This did not work but I can see where what you were trying to get. it seems to be a type issue... I have however just found this... but cant get the reliant info: 'gwmi -cl win32_reliabilityRecords'

Comment: This lists out some times: *gwmi -cl win32_reliabilityRecords | select timegenerated*

Comment: there is a nice alternative usin com object, I'm updating answer.

Comment: I have a list of installed dates, Fantastic!

Comment: The 2nd option require running windows update service. First one works even windows update service is disabled

Answer (score 6):

Here you have how to know the date and time of the last Windows update in a single line of Powershell:

```
(New-Object -com "Microsoft.Update.AutoUpdate"). Results | fl
```

You also have the following script to check it massively in Windows Server:

```
$ servers = Get-ADComputer -Filter {(OperatingSystem-like "* windows * server *") -and (Enabled -eq "True")} -Properties OperatingSystem | Sort Name | select -Unique Name

foreach ($ server in $ servers) {
write-host $ server.Name

   Invoke-Command -ComputerName $ server.Name -ScriptBlock {
(New-Object -com "Microsoft.Update.AutoUpdate"). Results}
}
```

Extracted from: https://www.sysadmit.com/2019/03/windows-update-ver-fecha-powershell.html

Comment: I wonder what is the diff to the other answer Get-HotFix |?{$_.InstalledOn -gt ((Get-Date).AddDays(-30))}. Your answer shows my last update from today, the other did not but shows more updates with kbnumber.

Answer (score 5):

`Get-HotFix |?{$_.InstalledOn -gt ((Get-Date).AddDays(-30))}`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Answer (score 2):

Using PowerShell, you can get the date of the las Windows update like this:

```
$lastWindowsUpdate = (Get-Hotfix | Sort-Object -Property InstalledOn -Descending | Select-Object -First 1).InstalledOn
```

Answer (score 0):

**Pre-PowerShell 7**

Users can use the code by [Loïc MICHEL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33732971/4512719) for querying via WMI:

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_QuickFixEngineering | Sort-Object -Property InstalledOn -Descending
```

**Post-PowerShell 7**

PowerShell 7 deprecated WMI as a result of switching to .NET Core.  Instead, you can utilize CIM

```
Get-CimInstance Win32_QuickFixEngineering | Sort-Object -Property InstalledOn -Descending
```

**Alternative**

[kayess](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51749134/4512719) and [Martin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75540427/4512719) posted excellent, simple example using [Get-HotFix](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-hotfix?view=powershell-7.3&WT.mc_id=email), which works for PowerShell 5.1 through 7.3 (and possibly other versions as well).

```
Get-HotFix | Sort-Object -Property InstalledOn -Descending
```