# Powershell to list all the microsoft updates on a computer?

Tags: powershell

I am trying to figure out a script that'll help me list all the Microsoft updates installed on my system. 
I am using

```
Get-Hotfix
```

to do the same but i am not getting desired results. Neither is:

```
 Get-WmiObject -Class "win32_quickfixengineering" |
 where $_.name = "Microsoft"
```

this working for me.
Please help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33732971/381149

Comment: Will this get me just the Microsoft updates or all of them, because that's what i have already done.

Comment: What non-Microsoft updates do you see when running this ?

Comment: Actually the thing is i cannot see name of the updates but just the hotfix ID.

Comment: did you try using the COM object Microsoft.Update.Session  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use this script (didn't find a way to display the description with `Get-HotFix`).

It lists the programs found in the `Uninstall` keys of the windows registry, and matches the name againt the `$filter` string.

You can remotely get this information from another computer by changing `$computerName` (currently the local host).

```
#store computer name in a variable
$computerName = $env:COMPUTERNAME

#store filter string in a variable
$filter = "KB"

#declare results array
$result = @()

#store registry key paths in an array
$keyList = 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\',
           'SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\'

#open registry hive HKLM
$hive = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey([Microsoft.Win32.RegistryHive]::LocalMachine, $computerName)

#for each key path
foreach($key in $keyList) {

    #open key
    $uninstallKey = $hive.OpenSubKey($key)

    #if key has been opened
    if($uninstallKey) {

        #list program keys
        $programList = $uninstallKey.GetSubKeyNames()

        #for each key
        foreach($program in $programList) {

            #get the program name
            $programName = $uninstallKey.OpenSubKey($program).GetValue("DisplayName")

            #if the program name is not null and matches our filter
            if(($programName) -and ($programName -like "*$filter*")) {

                #add program name to results array
                $result += $programName
            }
        }
    }
}

#sort and output results array
$result | Sort-Object
```

Comment: This works for me, but as i am very not that good in powershell, can you please explain what is happening here ?

Comment: I will provide some explanation (I'm at work, I have to find some spare time ^^)

Comment: yeah sure. Also i would like to know, why filter is 'KB'.

Comment: Because their "short name" is usually `KBXXXXXXX`. So you now realize another unrelated program with "KB" in the name would be caught in this net ^^. Not the best net ever, but you can always improve it : ).