# How can I check how long ago the last windows update has been installed with a powershell script?

Tags: powershell

I'm looking to write a powershell script that checks the date the last windows update has been installed on the client, check if it has been over a week (the script is to be run monthly, a week after patchday), and if it has, an email is to be sent to the user telling them to connect to the WSUS Server ASAP to get the newest updates.
I have very limited experience using powershell so if anyone here has some input it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Powershell, How to get date of last Windows update install or at least checked for an update?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33732541/powershell-how-to-get-date-of-last-windows-update-install-or-at-least-checked-f)

Comment: it looks promising, i will check it out, thank you

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code should work:

```
$lastupdate = (get-wmiobject -class win32_quickfixengineering).installedon | Sort-Object -Property installedon -Descending
$Date = Get-Date

$diff = New-TimeSpan -Start $lastupdate[0] -end $Date
if ($diff.days -ge 7) {

#Script to send email goes here

}
```

Note: This needs to be run as administrator.

Comment: this does exactly what i was looking for, and is much simpler than the approach i tried before, thank you very much my friend

Comment: Any time, glad to help