# is there a way to check the update status of my wsus clients using powershell, and send out emails to users that have not updated their clients?

Tags: powershell

I already asked a similar question a while back ([How can I check how long ago the last windows update has been installed with a powershell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69929681/how-can-i-check-how-long-ago-the-last-windows-update-has-been-installed-with-a-p/69956889?noredirect=1#comment123708352_69956889)), but now realised that the approach i took back then doesn't work, is there a way to check update status of my wsus clients using powershell, and send an email to the user if their system isn't up to date ?

Answer (score 0):

The command to run on your windows clients to force them to check in on demand:

```
$updateSession = new-object -com "Microsoft.Update.Session"; $updates=$updateSession.CreateupdateSearcher().Search($criteria).Updates
```

Running this command will "prime" the Windows Update engine to submit its most recent status on the next poll. To trigger that next poll, use:

```
wuauclt /reportnow
```

Comment: the problem is that our clients are often being used outside of our own network (when supporting customers on premise) for extended periods, meaning even if the command is run to force a check in, it may not work since they simply have no connection to the wsus server, that's why i'm trying to solve this in the way i described

Comment: @AalHai can you check this link and let me know is it helpful or not- https://www.majorgeeks.com/content/page/how_to_check_your_windows_update_history_with_powershell.html#:~:text=Press%20the%20Windows%20Key%20%2B%20X,%2C%20installed%20date%2C%20and%20more.

Comment: this seems to be a script that is run on the client itself right ?

Comment: You can also get the update history on remote computers by typing in wmic /node: 'computer name' qfe > filename.txt.

Comment: i will give it a shot, thanks for your input

Comment: Sure check it once @AalHai